# Difference between absdiff and normal subtraction in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, classification, image-classification

I am currently planning on training a binary image classification model.  The images I want to train on are the difference between two original pictures.  In other words, for each data entry, I start out with 2 pictures, take their difference, and the label that difference as a 0 or 1.  My question is what is the best way to find this difference.  I know about `cv2.absdiff` and then normal subtraction of images - what is the most effective way to go about this?

About the data: The images I'm training on are screenshots that usually are the same but may have small differences.  I found that normal subtraction seems to show the differences less than absdiff.

This is the code I use for absdiff:

```py
diff = cv2.absdiff(img1, img2)

mask = cv2.cvtColor(diff, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

th = 1
imask =  mask>1

canvas = np.zeros_like(img2, np.uint8)
canvas[imask] = img2[imask]
```

And then this for normal subtraction:

```py
def extract_diff(self,imageA, imageB, image_name, path):
    subtract = imageB.astype(np.float32) - imageA.astype(np.float32)
    mask = cv2.inRange(np.abs(subtract),(30,30,30),(255,255,255))
        
    th = 1
    imask =  mask>1
    
    canvas = np.zeros_like(imageA, np.uint8)
    canvas[imask] = imageA[imask]
```

Thanks!

Comment: those two snippets of code don't just differ in how they calculate a difference, but in *what* they do with it (convert to gray vs. `inRange`). please separate these issues.

Comment: Ok lets separate the issues.  I'd still like to know what is the best combination

Answer (score 3):

A difference can be negative or positive.

For some number types, such as uint8 (unsigned 8-bit int), which can't be negative (have no sign), a negative value wraps around and the value would make no sense anymore. Other types can be signed (e.g. floats, signed ints), so a negative value can be represented correctly.

That's why `cv.absdiff` exists. It always gives you **absolute differences**, and those are okay to represent in an unsigned type.

Example with numbers: `a = 4, b = 6`. `a-b` should be `-2`, right?

That value, as an `uint8`, will wrap around to become `0xFE`, or `254` in decimal. The 254 value has *some* relation to the true -2 difference, but it also incorporates the range of values of the data type (8 bits: 256 values), so it's really just "code".

`cv.absdiff` would give you the absolute of the difference (-2), which is `2`.